# Blender2.77 layout sharing

Tags: interface

How do I share a Blender2.77 layout with other Blender2.77 users? I have saved it on my computer but have not saved it with other Blender user computers.

Comment: On which system do you use Blender?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new layout in the Themes tab in the User preferences, then a xml file gets created in the Blender app data folder. At Windows 7 it's

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\presets\interface_theme

Let's say you added a new preset and named it mytheme, then you will find a mytheme.xml in the above folder.

You can grab this xml file, and other users can then install this xml file as a new theme with the Install Theme button in the Themes tab in the User Preferences.

[image]

Comment: If the layout includes specific videos and still images made for it, will it share those too when I share the layout with others?

Comment: Content is not part of the layout. That's part of the current scene. So when you want to share content, then you need a blend file. Plus the dependencies, means the used images and videos. The images are not embedded when you don't explicitely embed them. They are linked externally.